# What are options to debug a React Native + Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have been researching options to debug a React Native + Redux app. Especially the redux part. What is your preferred way to do this? Hope to know!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you all for the recommendations, I tried out the four options!
I even wrote [a medium article](https://medium.com/@tetsuyahasegawa/comparing-4-ways-to-debug-redux-in-an-expo-app-f61ed6c9635b) on this topic.

My conclusion, 
Use [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger). ([Guide to setup](https://medium.com/@tetsuyahasegawa/how-to-integrate-react-native-debugger-to-your-expo-react-native-project-db1d631fad02))

Since,

v.s. [redux-logger](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger): lacks functionality, additional dependency per project

v.s. [Remote Redux Devtools](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools): lacks functionality, additional dependency per project, additional code.

v.s. [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron): Unfamiliar interface, additional dependencies per project, additional code.

Answer (score 9):

I use [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) as stand-alone-version for this.
It is able to show the full history of redux-state changes and give you some handy tools like Raw-View, Chart-View or Diff-View.
And you don't have to add anything in your App-Code (like for Reactotron).

It looks like this:

[image]

To activate the Redux-Panel, you only do a right-click at the Debugger window and choose `Toggle redux devtools`.

Comment: Agree! I wrote a guide to setup React Native Debugger! https://medium.com/@tetsuyahasegawa/how-to-integrate-react-native-debugger-to-your-expo-react-native-project-db1d631fad02

Comment: Does it support JSI debugging?

Comment: React navigation causes the react-native-debugger to stop working for me. Searches suggest that the time difference between the two devices is causing it to do so. i am unable to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use DevTools, but that's a Chrome extension and not for Simulator. Perhaps you can look into remote monitoring with it: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/remote-redux-devtools I believe you would be able to set this up to monitor Store interactions in Simulator remotely.

Edit: Yes it actually is meant for React Native after reading more of the README. I would use this for sure.

Comment: For on the spot solution Remote Redux devtools was indeed a good option! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple tools are beneficial for developers when dealing with `redux`, and out of all of em, I highly recommend using both below

[Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron):

```
- view your application state
- show API requests & responses
- perform quick performance benchmarks
- subscribe to parts of your application state
- display messages similar to console.log
- track global errors with source-mapped stack traces including saga stack - traces!
- dispatch actions like a government-run mind control experiment
- hot swap your app's state using Redux or mobx-state-tree
- track your sagas
- show image overlay in React Native
- track your Async Storage in React Native
```

[Redux-logger](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger):

It helps to show you the `previous state`, `current action payload` and `next state` whenever we dispatch a redux action, which you should see how it's benefiting us

Comment: Reactotron did have many cool funcs! I loved how lightweight redux-logger solution is. Thank you!